# How to expect a multiple method is been called with Jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Having this code

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadFilesList(this.massiveLoadModuleConfig.CONSTANTS.FILES_LIST_REFRESH_INTERVAL);
}

private loadFilesList(interval: number): void {
    this.massiveLoadService.loadMassiveLoadFilesList().subscribe(() => this.getFilesList());

    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.loadFilesList(interval);
    }, interval);
}
```

How can I expect in Jasmine the method "massiveLoadService.loadMassiveLoadFilesList()" to have been called multiple times?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know the number of times this specific function is being called? If yes, then you can use 'expect(whatever your spy method is).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(Number of times)'.

Answer (score 1):

- Use `fakeAsync` + `tick`
- We only want to test if the loadFilesList() call after amount time again

```
it ('...', fakeAsync(() => {
  const spy = spyOn(massiveLoadService, 'loadFilesList').and.callThrough();
  fixture.detectChanges(); // detect change againt

  tick(); // invoke async
  tick(yourInterval);

  fixture.detectChanges(); // detect change againt
  fixture.destroy(); // kill the interval, otherwise it will continue running = error

  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
})
```

**Note**: I would not use nested function + setInterval like that to repeat a function,
I would use `timer()` from rxjs for a better implementation